# Android Universal Image Loader Timeout

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I am using [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for Downloading Image from an URL.Because My Image Size is large,Image Loader reach 5 second timeout and throw an exception. How can I increase ImageLoader Time out?
Also you must know, I found below code but it didn't work because this library hasn't this function.

`imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(5 * 1000, 20 * 1000));`

my ImageLoaderConfig :

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Comment: I think you can use http://square.github.io/picasso/ instead of universal image loader because picasso is the best image loader for android :)

Comment: Thank you for your great help.Surly I'll test it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context, 5 * 1000, 20 * 1000))
    .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```